# Create an Entry in /proc

Tags: linux-kernel

I have successfully created a pseudo Hello World Entry with a LKM.

http://pointer-overloading.blogspot.co.at/2013/09/linux-creating-entry-in-proc-file.html

However in my init function, i have one integer value which i want to return in "cat /proc/example".

Any Ideas how to do this in this code?

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/seq_file.h>

static int hello_proc_show(struct seq_file *m, void *v) {
  seq_printf(m, "Hello proc!\n");
  return 0;
}

static int hello_proc_open(struct inode *inode, struct  file *file) {
  return single_open(file, hello_proc_show, NULL);
}

static const struct file_operations hello_proc_fops = {
  .owner = THIS_MODULE,
  .open = hello_proc_open,
  .read = seq_read,
  .llseek = seq_lseek,
  .release = single_release,
};

static int __init hello_proc_init(void) {
  proc_create("hello_proc", 0, NULL, &hello_proc_fops);
  return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_proc_exit(void) {
  remove_proc_entry("hello_proc", NULL);
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
module_init(hello_proc_init);
module_exit(hello_proc_exit);
```

Comment: Your provided code does not show any integer value in an `init` function?

Comment: In my Code i have an integer value for the CPU temperature. i just want to return this value instead of "Hello World". Do i need to to add another data to my struct or can i just give it to the provided functions?

Comment: seq_printf(m, "CPU Temp : %d \n", cpu_temp);  ?

Answer (score -1):

If procfs is not the strict requirement then make use of '*kobject*' to create the `sysfs` entry. Refer below example and modify `foo_show` function as per your requirement. Otherwise, the comment from @mali will do the trick.

https://github.com/saiyamd/linux/blob/master/samples/kobject/kobject-example.c